# Proving $1-(-2)^{n+1}+3(-2)^{n+1}=1-(-2)^{n+2}$

Tags: arithmetic

I have this equality

$$1-(-2)^{n+1}+3(-2)^{n+1}=1-(-2)^{n+2}$$

Can anyone show me how the LHS can be equal to the RHS here? I can't really see it.

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: If you write $a$ for $(-1)^{n+1}$ what you need to prove is $1-a+3a=1-(-2)a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$1-(-2)^{n+1}+3(-2)^{n+1}=-\frac12 \left( -2-(-2)^{n+2}+3(-2)^{n+2}\right)=1-(-2)^{n+2}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify it as follows:$$1-(-2)^{n+1}+3(-2)^{n+1}=1-(-2)^{n+1}(1-3)$$